# Updating tableview causes lag and warning

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have an array that contains data retrieved from a fetch request.  Above my tableview I have a button that initiates another fetch request with a filter.  Whenever I hit the button, I empty the array containing the files from the previous fetch request, which is also the same array that I use to refer to the `numberOfRowInSection`.  The array is then filled with the data from the new request.  This works, but there is a huge lag between when I hit the button and the table view is reloaded with the new data.

I then get the warning "This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release."

I read in another post that I need to implement `dispatch_async`, but I'm not sure where:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
// code here
})
```

Remaining code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {       
        return self.recordings.count

}

@IBAction func publicButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.recordings.removeAll()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        do {
            let dict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary
            self.fetchedArray = dict!["recordings"] as? NSArray
            print("fetched array count \(self.fetchedArray!.count)")

            if let jsonArray: NSArray = self.fetchedArray {

                for var i=0; i<jsonArray.count; ++i {

                    let dictResult = jsonArray.objectAtIndex(i) as! NSDictionary

                    let recording = Recordings()
                    recording.trackURL = dictResult["url"] as? String
                    self.recordings.append(recording)                    
                }  
            }
            else
            {
                // No error thrown, but no NSDictionary
            }
            self.audioTable.reloadData()
        }
        catch let parseError {
            // Log the error thrown by `JSONObjectWithData`
        }

    })        
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything to do with UI needs to be on the main thread. In your code this will be the `reloadData` call. So modify your code to wrap the `reloadData` inside a `dispatch_async`

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
  self.audioTable.reloadData()
})
```